# ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED error macbook pro

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, safari, vpn

ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
Hide details
If you use a proxy server…
Check your proxy settings or contact your network administrator to make sure that the proxy server is working. If you don't believe you should be using a proxy server: Go to Applications > System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and deselect any proxies that have been selected.

- I cleared cache, restarted computer, reinstalled Chrome a few times, cleaned computer;
  _ I TRY WITH 4 VPN (HOTSPOT SHIELD ,EXPREES VPN, OPENVPN, .....)
  _ I don't have any proxies checked in Settings > Network > Network > Advanced > Proxies;
- The same problem happens with different Internet connections (work, home, etc).
- What is interesting in Private Mode everything's okay.
  Any suggestions how to fix that? I only found solutions for Windows, there's nothing regarding Mac (macOS Bigsur).